# UI bootstrap timepicker - how to disable user input for only the minutes

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I would like to disable user input for timepicker, but only for the minutes, because I want to limit the users such that they can only select 00, 15, 30, and 45.

I would still like to allow users to input the hours, else it may be tedious for users to change the hour if the only way to change it is to click the up/down arrows.